# Run a bash script in docker-compose

Tags: apache, docker, ssl, https, docker-compose

I'm trying to bring up an OwnCloud container on my docker server via docker compose. I'm using the stock OwnCloud image from Docker Hub. Here is my yaml file:

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  owncloud:
    image: owncloud
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - '/etc/docker/owncloud/data:/var/www/html'
      - '/etc/docker/owncloud/ssl.sh:/etc/apache2/ssl.sh'
    networks:
        default:
            ipv4_address: 192.168.226.28
  mysql:
    image: mariadb
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ********
volumes:
    owncloud_data:
        driver: local
networks:
    default:
        external:
            name: pub_net
```

It works great. The container comes up and I can access it via http. Now of course I want to access via https so you can see bash script I've sent into my container. Here are the contents of that script:

```
#!/bin/bash
a2enmod ssl
a2ensite default-ssl
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 99999 -newkey rsa:2048 -subj "/C=US/ST=Ohio/L=Cleveland/O=Data/CN=fake.domain.com" -keyout /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key -out /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
service apache2 restart
```

Now, if I manually bash into the container and run that script it works great. I can access OwnCloud via https. Here's where it get's annoying. I want to automate the process of running that script so when the container updates its part of the rebuild process. So far I've tried adding a "command" string in the yaml file like this:

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  owncloud:
    image: owncloud
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - '/etc/docker/owncloud/data:/var/www/html'
      - '/etc/docker/owncloud/ssl.sh:/etc/apache2/ssl.sh'
    networks:
        default:
            ipv4_address: 192.168.226.28
    command: /etc/apache2/ssl.sh
  mysql:
    image: mariadb
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ********
volumes:
    owncloud_data:
        driver: local
networks:
    default:
        external:
            name: pub_net
```

When I run docker-compose up it does appear to run the script, except it runs it over and over again, and the apache service keeps restarting. Here is a snippet of the logs:

```
Restarting Apache httpd web server: apache2.

Considering dependency setenvif for ssl:

Module setenvif already enabled

Considering dependency mime for ssl:

Module mime already enabled

Considering dependency socache_shmcb for ssl:

Module socache_shmcb already enabled

dule ssl already enabled

Site default-ssl already enabled

Generating a RSA private key

................+++++

...............+++++

writing new private key to '/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key'

-----

AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.226.28. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message

[Wed Oct 07 21:09:05.504798 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 33] AH01906: 192.168.226.28:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)

[Wed Oct 07 21:09:05.504883 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 33] AH01909: 192.168.226.28:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

Restarting Apache httpd web server: apache2.

Considering dependency setenvif for ssl:

Module setenvif already enabled

Considering dependency mime for ssl:

Module mime already enabled

Considering dependency socache_shmcb for ssl:

Module socache_shmcb already enabled

dule ssl already enabled

Site default-ssl already enabled

Generating a RSA private key

....................................+++++

...............................+++++

writing new private key to '/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key'

-----

AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.226.28. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message

[Wed Oct 07 21:09:15.145928 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 33] AH01906: 192.168.226.28:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)

[Wed Oct 07 21:09:15.146014 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 33] AH01909: 192.168.226.28:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

Restarting Apache httpd web server: apache2.

Considering dependency setenvif for ssl:

Module setenvif already enabled

Considering dependency mime for ssl:

Module mime already enabled

Considering dependency socache_shmcb for ssl:

Module socache_shmcb already enabled

dule ssl already enabled

Site default-ssl already enabled

Generating a RSA private key

...........................+++++

..........................................+++++

writing new private key to '/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key'

-----

AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.226.28. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message

[Wed Oct 07 21:09:29.712422 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 33] AH01906: 192.168.226.28:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)

[Wed Oct 07 21:09:29.712500 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 33] AH01909: 192.168.226.28:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
```

I'm not sure where to go from here. Any ideas?

Comment: use an entrypoint script instead. search *entrypoint.sh docker* your find loads of examples.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I actually tried this course as well and had the same outcome. It just looped the entry point script over and over. The answer from Vith below worked as I intended. I believe his solution would also work when implementing this as an entrypoint script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker container command should run for as long as you expect for container to run.

When your script starts, there is completely nothing else running in container. There is no apache2 or anything, just your script. And it ends with `service apache2 restart` and quits right after. It doesn't care about any background processes that you just started. It only cares that your foreground process - your bash script - has finished already.

As you can see in your image (using latest version at time of writing this): https://hub.docker.com/layers/owncloud/library/owncloud/latest/images/sha256-57e690e039c947e4de6bdae767b57b402d3ed9b9ed9f12ba5d31d3cf92def4b8?context=explore it is using `CMD ["apache2-foreground"]` to run. And that's how you should end your bash script so it also runs apache2 in foreground:

```
#!/bin/bash
a2enmod ssl
a2ensite default-ssl
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 99999 -newkey rsa:2048 -subj "/C=US/ST=Ohio/L=Cleveland/O=Data/CN=fake.domain.com" -keyout /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key -out /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
apache2-foreground
```

Comment: I added the apache2-foreground command at the end of my bash script and, voila! It works exactly as I intended. Thank you so much!